# retrieve query outside the wordpress loop with ajax.load in #content

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am working on an advanced search on wordpress based on custom taxonomies.
I'm stuck since 48h so I was hoping to have some help or thought...

**Step 1** --- in the js file the query strings are created like that:

```
if (jQuery('#s').val() == ''){
URL = "/?genre=" + genre + '...other Stuff' #content';
}else{
URL = "/?s="+searchQueryString+"&genre=" + genre +'...other stuff' #content';
}
```

It nicelly load my custom loop in my #content div without changing the browser url or reloading the header, which is pretty good...so far. :-)

**Step 2** --- then I wrote 2 functions in my function.php , one to load the loop with the GET[] elements on main page, using `new WP_Query` 
and one that does the same thing for search queries:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');
```

Which is compiling my GET[] filters with the GET[s] in the content.php,
Still all good....

**Step 3** --- (problem^^)---

I want to add a css class to desactivate the radio buttons located in my header.php, depending on the results in the loop.

**Try-1** I thought I could create a php array to compile the terms found while the loop is happening, and then compare it with my buttons value.like that:

```
$args = array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'slugs');
$results = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(),'category',$args);  
foreach ($results as $result){
    array_push($stack, $result);

}
```

But there is no way to retrieve the data from that array in the header afterwhile, or to create it from the header using things like `global $post;`since my url doesn't change.
it just shows the homepage query.

**Try-2** I also thought I could encode it to json and then put some action in my js file. but so far it just return json unexpected character, and I got the feeling that even if I crack it, its not going to be the right way since its going to make the js file heavier.

May be I'm just missing something about the Global wp_query and I don't need to charge my script?

Excuse my english and the long question,

thanks a lot in advance if you have an idea,

DACO

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use [wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to export the array to my js script,
Thanks sorted